# Redirecting old unused domain to new domain will help to increase Google authority?

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search-console

I have been doing blogging since 5 years back and from last year i had stopped blogging and delete the domain content. (During last year all pages are removed from indexed )

now I had purchased a new domain [BlogTechie](http://www.blogtechie.com) and i am planning to 301 redirect that old domain to new domain.

Is It helped to gain SEO authority in Google or I should start from scratch without worrying about old domain.

I am also adding settings in webmaster tools to inform Google for the change.

Answer (score 0):

SEOs attribute a large portion of most search engines' ranking algorithms to link-based factors.  It's possible there may be old links to your pages out there on the internet on other websites.  You can capitalize on this if you still own the old URL and boost your new domain's ranking with redirects.

If you know some of your older content's URLs, it might make sense to have a one to one redirect to the new page.  If you're using apache, you can do this with an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /folder/oldpage.php http://www.newdomain.org/newpage.php
```

Anything remaining can redirect to the root.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

Check out SEO Moz for more explanation on this: http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection